# Django custom tags in textfield

Tags: django, django-models, tags, django-templates

I don't know this is the right title to tell my question but I couldn't think any other to tell.
I want to put some custom tags to textfield. For example, if I write "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (srch: who am i)" as input I want to render this text as it is but with a difference, when I click who am i, I want to direct it to example.com/who-am-i. So if I but (srch: something) it should have a link to example.com/something.
How can I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide us more information about where you want to do that, what is the part done in the view, and what is the part handled in the template?

Comment: I don't know where to handle it. It does not matter for me. I just want to make the transformation between unlinked (such: sth) to linked (such: sth) but I don't have any opinions. Also I have a few other transformations but I think if I can do this I can handle the others.

Comment: @user3416136 Do you want to do the transformation when fetching the string from the database? Or does it have to happen while typing (with some sort of javascript)?

Comment: I handled it with templatetags. Thanks anyway. I forgot to update here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@register.filter
@stringfilter
def bkz(value, autoescape=None):
    value = re.sub(r'(.*)\(bkz: (.*)\b\)',r'\1(bkz: <a href="/baslik/">\2</a>)',value)
    return mark_safe(value)
bkz.is_safe=True
bkz.needs_autoescape = True
```

This templatetag worked fine for me.